# Is there any way to execute a MATLAB script through Javascript?

Tags: javascript, matlab

Title question says it all, I have a function written in MATLAB that I rewriting to Javascript, but I got around to wondering whether executing it from Javascript would be possible?

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16045527/combining-matlab-javascript-methods-of-integration) possible duplicate.

Comment: If you know Java, and can afford new software, [see this](http://www.mathworks.com/products/new_products/webserver_discontinued.html?s_cid=r2006b_webserver). [This PDF](http://www.mathworks.com/help/pdf_doc/compiler/example_guide.pdf) goes through the details, including interacting with the Java via JavaScript. Not pretty.

Comment: You can easily set up MATLAB as a web-server and then do ajax-calls from JavaScript. See https://github.com/decatur/NuCompRes to get you started (disclosure: I'm the author). However, if the MATLAB code is simple and computational lightweight, then translating to JavaScript is probably the better solution.

Answer (score 1):

There is no script, at this moment, to convert MATLAB to JavaScript (it's tedious but not impossible to write a parser for M code using a generator like jison). If you posted your MATLAB code, we could find equivalents for some commands (like matrix multiplication ), but there is no general technique.

You could also run MATLAB on your server (there is a UNIX version and server licensing) and send commands to a running session from the website.

Answer (score 0):

This toolbox on the MathWorks File Exchange (https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/69973-generate-javascript-using-matlab-coder) can compile MATLAB functions into JavaScript functions that can be run in a browser. While this solution would be running the compiled code, it would allow your MATLAB algorithm to be executed in your web page.